# Build and View as Ctrl/cmd+s instead of F5 in TeXStudio

Tags: macros, compiling, binding

So I have just changed my LaTeX editor to Texstudio instead of VSCode and I can't really get used to building my document on F5 instead of Ctrl (cmd) + S as in VSCode. Is there any way I can bind the Build and View command to Ctrl+S instead of F5? I have little to no experience in general in changing commands and bindings etc., so please bear with me

Comment: As far as I can see there is a 'Shortcuts' item in the TeXStudio configuration where you can add additional shortcuts to existing functions.

Comment: Go to `Options` in the drop down menus at the top, then select `Configure TeXstudio` then choose `Shortcuts` from the list on the left. Then choose `Tools` and it will expand to show `Build view` which will have the `default shortcut` and the `current shortcut` listed. You can either change the current shortcut by double clicking on it or add a second shortcut by double clicking in the space under the `additional shortcut` either way you will get a drop down list and you can select `ctrl` + `s` as the new shortcut

Comment: Thank you both of you. I got it working. I had looked at the shortcuts but apparently not very well.. Thanks for your quick replies!